# JavaScript to open two web pages using one link

Tags: javascript, html

I need JavaScript code or HTML to make two websites open in two new browser tabs when clicking on one link. I do not want them to open in new windows, or on the current page that the link is on.

Comment: You cannot control opening in new window vs new tab from javascript. It depends on browser settings and you can't control it

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript

Answer (score 3):

It probably won't work because the browser might consider it a popup and block it.

If the user allows popups you can do:

```
window.open(url, '_blank');
```

Like:

```
<a id="mydoublelink" href="http://site1.com" target="_blank">foo</a>

document.getElementById("mydoublelink").onclick=function(){
    window.open('http://site2.com', '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Most browser popup-blockers allow popups that are spawned from a click-event (and some others). So it will work unless you have a very aggressive popup-blocker.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen added "probably" to the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

If you call `window.open` in the `onclick` event you should be fine. Built-in popup blockers **allow** those. The kind of popups that get blocked come from other events or from scheduled events like a `setTimeout`.

```
document.getElement("my_link").onclick = function () {
    window.open(/*..*/); // works
}

document.getElement("my_link").onclick = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.open(/*..*/); // will probably get blocked
    });
}
```

This means, for instance, that if you open a popup after an AJAX call it will very likely get blocked. A workaround in this case is to open the popup right away and fill in the content later. This is outside the scope of this question but I feel like this is information that everyone should know.

Comment: i want to open two links in onclick on the link..but i dont want to close the current tab..both link muse be opened on another two tabs

Comment: Then call `window.open()` _twice_

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function open_win() 
{
window.open("URL");
open_win_two();
}
function open_win_two()
{
window.open("URL");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a onclick="open_win()">luyfl</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yu can try the new target `_newtab`:

```
<a href="site.html" target="_newtab">blabla</a>
```

It works in Firefox, don't know if it's supported in other browsers.

Comment: Unless I've missed my guess, this will just open `site.html` in a new window that happens to be named "_newtab". Clicking on the link again will open the page again in the same window. Whether or not this is actually a new tab depends on how the user has set up their browser. It could just as easily open in a new browser window.

Comment: This is new behaviour that is starting to be implemented in browsers, not just the plain old behaviour your are thinking about.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that :) Do you have a link to any documentation?